# Why would setting the interrupted status too early before a blocking call cause infinite loop?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am reading "Concurrency in practice" and in chapter 6 under "responding to interruption" it says that

"Setting the interrupted status too early could result in an infinite loop, because most interruptible blocking methods check the interrupted status on entry and throw InterruptedException immediately if it is set.(Interruptible methods usually poll for interruption before blocking or doing any significant work, so as to be as responsive to interruption before blocking or doing any significant work, so as to be as responsive to interruption as possible)"

```
public Task getNextTask(BlockingQueue<Task> queue) {
        boolean interrupted = false;
        try {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    return queue.take();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    interrupted = true;
                   // fall through and retry
                }
            }
        } finally {
            if (interrupted)
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
}
```

let's say the code was

```
public Task getNextTask(BlockingQueue<task> queue){
boolean interrupted=false;
        while(true){
        /*i get this part that before the take() function threads     interrupted status is checked*/
            return queue.take();
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
                interrupted=true;
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
    }//end of while
}
```

Now why would the last function cause an infinite loop as i have setted the interruption status of the threrad back to false , as per my understanding , during the blocking call's polling for interruption status of the thread it will check if it is set which it will find it as false and then continue with the call . So where did the infinite loop come into the picture ?

Comment: The second code will not even compile. And the first code snippet my fall into infinite loop if `queue.take` is always interrupted and never returns anything.

Comment: @michalk can you provide a clearer example to explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `InterruptedException` would be thrown because the `take()` method checks for interruption. This check/throw typically takes the form:

```
if (Thread.currentThread.interrupted()) {  // Checks and clears the interrupted flag.
  throw new InterruptedException();
}
```

You then catch the `InterruptedException`, restoring the interruption flag, and call `take()` again. That checks for interruption, finds that the thread has been interrupted, and then throws `InterruptedException`.

You then catch the `InterruptedException`, restoring the interruption flag, and call `take()` again. That checks for interruption, finds that the thread has been interrupted, and then throws `InterruptedException`.

You then catch the `InterruptedException`, restoring the interruption flag, and call `take()` again. That checks for interruption, finds that the thread has been interrupted, and then throws `InterruptedException`.

etc.

Comment: If a reset has been called then why would the code that checks for interruption throw InterruptedException because now it's interrupted status has been cleared ?

Comment: I have reworded "resetting" to "restoring".

Comment: So once a Thread is interrupted and it throws InterruptedException , it's interrupted flag gets cleared ? So in the above written code if i put 
"if (Thread.currentThread.interrupted())" in the catch block , it will come to be false ?

Comment: @GaganSingh not necessarily. The interrupted flag and interrupted exception are orthogonal mechanisms to indicate interruption. `Thread.interrupted()` clears the interrupted flag, `Thread.isInterrupted()` does not. But `interrupted()` tends to be used immediately before throwing an exception so the flag is cleared, in order that it doesn't look "doubly-interrupted" (which isn't a thing; it's just a confusing state for the person handling the exception).